# Cannot import torch Error loading ..\caffe2_nvrtc.dll" or one of its dependencies

Tags: pytorch, windows-10

I am on a Windows 10 64 bit system.
Pytorch for cuda has been working successfully for some time.
Today I tried to upgrade to the latest version of Pytorch (1.13) using

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Now I cannot import torch. I get the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\alan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I have tried both in a Jupyter notebook and in the Spyder IDE.

I have tried completely removing Anaconda and reinstalling afresh and then reinstalling Pytorch with no success.
I do not believe I have any other versions of python installed.

The offending dll (caffe2_nvrtc.dll) does seem to be in the file location specified.

I have found various similar problems reported but they all date back to 2020 or earlier and none of them seemed to have a satisfactory solution.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why using conda did not work but I tried again using pip
and that did work

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem as yours today.

[image: spyder error report image]

It turns out that when I use the anaconda prompt then the problem disappears.
Anaconda prompt could do it

[image: Anaconda prompt could do it]

Then I speculated that the only difference between these two scenarios is that when I use the anaconda prompt, I use the base anaconda environment, probably somehow the conda environment in spyder is not activated.

So the solution is to open the spyder in anaconda prompt like this:

[image: base environment spyder]

Then it works.

[image: It turns out to work]

This picture will tell you the cause for the problem.
[problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oITgj.png)

Comment: I understand your reasoning but when I type 'python' at the command prompt nothing happens. It does not ccomplain and does not enter the python interpreter. It simply returns the directory name and the forward arrow. It also opens up a window to the Microsoft store to get python. If I run it with a program name eg python fred.py I get         :
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases. So I do not seem to be able to run python outside of the base environment

Comment: Try this solution:" https://github.com/alievk/avatarify-python/issues/116 "

Comment: Beacuse the path of python interpreter has not been registered in the windows environment variable. So windows cmd couldn't find the python command interpreter.

Comment: For the purpose of searchability and future accessability. Please avoid screenshots and insert code & relevant parts as text. Thank you.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. It was solved by installing cudatoolkit (based on this suggestion https://github.com/alievk/avatarify-python/issues/116#issuecomment-1331471088). I'm not sure why. The PyTorch website mentions the necessity to install cudatoolkit for earlier versions of PyTorch, but not for v2.

Answer (score 0):

The caffe2_nvrtc.dll library needs other Nvidia DLLs, which located in the **Bin** folder of your Conda installation. In particular, nvrtc64_112_0.dll.

Make sure you have the **bin** folder of your Conda installation in the **Path** environment variable.

On my computer, Conda is installed in the d:\anaconda3 folder. So the following paths are added to the Path user variable:

```
d:\anaconda3
d:\anaconda3\scripts
d:\anaconda3\bin
```